# What exception to raise for testcase: string length > value? - Python

Tags: python, exception, raise

I am doing some testing, in which I have some Raise in some cases like:

```
@staticmethod
def concat_strings(string1, string2):
    if type(string1) is not str or type (string2) is not str:
        raise TypeError
    return string1 + string2

@staticmethod
def concat_3strings(string1, string2, string3):
    if type(string1) is not str or type(string2) is not str or type(string3) is not str:
        raise TypeError
    return string1+string2+string3
```

Now, if I want to check that the length of the strings is 10 at max, would that be "attribute error", or what kind of raise should I do? Why that one?

For example:

```
    @staticmethod
    def concat_2strings_tam(string1, string2):
        if len(string1)>10 or len(string2)>10:
            raise AttributeError
        return string1+string2
```

Comment: Note that verifying types of of arguments is discouraged in Python, unless you're applying type annotations. (In which case doing it explicitly in your own code is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the python docs:

> exception ValueError
>
> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

So it sounds like you want `ValueError`, unless you want to define your own custom exception class.